# Executing a script when inserting a flash drive

Tags: usb, scripts, udev

How can I write a script that fires on an event?

When I insert an USB flash drive, Ubuntu mounts it and automatically opens Nautilus.
When this happens with a specific flash drive, I'd like to open a second tab with a determinate folder.

I don't think it can be done with a Nautilus script, but how can I do it with a Linux script or a Nautilus extension?

Comment: You could look into writing a [custom udev rule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in), but that can be quite complicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run the script below in the background, it checks for mounted volumes. If one of your defined drives is mounted, it automatically opens the set folder in nautilus.

A minor problem was that nautilus does not support opening a directory *in a new tab* from command line, only in a new window. That means that the initial window, that appears if you insert a usb drive, has to be gracefully closed. The script uses `wmctrl` to do that, at the same moment that your chosen folder will open.

You might need to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import time

#--
drivename_folders = [("My Passport", "docs"), ("7827-2F8C", "sanel")]
#--

def get_mountedlist():
    return [item[item.find("/"):] for item in subprocess.check_output(
            ["/bin/bash", "-c", "lsblk"]).decode("utf-8").split("\n") if "/" in item]

done = []

while True:
    mounted = get_mountedlist()
    new_paths = [dev for dev in mounted if not dev in done]
    valid = sum([[(drive, drive+"/"+item[1], item[0]) for drive in new_paths \
                  if item[0] in drive] for item in drivename_folders], [])

    for item in valid:
        open_window = "nautilus  "+"'"+item[1]+"'"
        close_window = "wmctrl -c  "+"'"+item[2]+"'"
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", open_window])
        time.sleep(1)
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", close_window])

    done = mounted
    time.sleep(2)
```

#### How to use

1. *Copy the script into an empty file*
2. *Set your drives and folders*

   In the head section of the script, change the line:

   ```
   drivename_folders = [("My Passport", "docs"), ("7827-2F8C", "MyFolder")]
   ```

   where every tuple represents a drive(name), and the folder inside the drive that has to be opened. I left my "test" -names as an example.
   If you are not sure about the exact name of your drive, run `lsblk` to see the name (without the preceding path to the mountpoint)
3. *Save the script*

   Save the script as `open_folder.py` and run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/open_folder.py
   ```

If all works as you expected, add it to your Startup Applications

#### How it works

- Every two seconds, the script runs the `lsblk` command to check for all mounted volumes.
- If it finds one or more newly mounted volume name(s), it checks if the name is in the list of volumes that you set to be opened in a specific way (opening a sub directory)
- The script opens the sub directory of the volume that you defined, and closes the (drive's root-) window that was automatically opened on connecting the drive.
- To prevent repeatedly opening the folders, the volume then is added to the "done" list, until the volume is unmounted.

#### Other file managers

I tested it on `pcmanfm` (Lubuntu) and `thunar` (Xubuntu) and, as expected, in both cases, it workes fine.

If you want to use it on either Lubuntu or Xubuntu, change the line:

```
open_window = "nautilus  "+"'"+item[1]+"'"
```

to:

```
open_window = "thunar "+"'"+item[1]+"'"
(for Xubuntu)
```

or

```
open_window = "pcmanfm "+"'"+item[1]+"'"
(for Lubuntu, also disable in pcmanfm's preferences: Media > "Show available options for removable media")
```

Of course, make sure `wmctrl` is installed

Most likely, it will work on other file managers as well.

---

#### Generalized version of the script

The version of the script above is specifically for one situation. To be able to use the script in a broader range of purposes (to run *any* command when a specific drive gets connected, making backups of it for example) the version below could be useful.

In this case, in the head section of the script, the tuples represent:

```
 drivename_folders = [(<drivename_a>, <command_a>), (<drivename_b>, <command_b>)]
```

see the "test" setting in the script below.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import time

#--
drivename_command = [("My Passport", "gnome-terminal"), ("F806-0C50", "gedit")]
#--

def get_mountedlist():
    return [item[item.find("/"):] for item in subprocess.check_output(
            ["/bin/bash", "-c", "lsblk"]).decode("utf-8").split("\n") if "/" in item]

done = []

while True:
    mounted = get_mountedlist()
    newly_mounted = [dev for dev in mounted if not dev in done]
    valid = sum([[(drive, item[1]) for drive in newly_mounted \
                  if item[0] in drive] for item in drivename_command], [])
    for item in valid:
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", item[1]])
    done = mounted
    time.sleep(2)
```

#### How to use

1. *Copy the script into an empty file*
2. *Set your drives and commands*
3. *Save the script*

   Save the script as `drive_run.py` and run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/drive_run.py
   ```

If all works as you expected, add it to your Startup Applications