# How can I autocopy files from pendrives?

Tags: usb, usb-drive, copy

How can I autocopy files from pendrives (in the background) to a folder in my computer when I connect any pendrive to it?

Comment: do use our search feature ;-) https://askubuntu.com/questions/562188/how-can-i-automatically-copy-the-content-of-a-usb-flash-drive-to-another-direc seems to exactly do what you ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I automatically copy the content of a usb (flash) drive to another directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562188/how-can-i-automatically-copy-the-content-of-a-usb-flash-drive-to-another-direc)

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question :)