# Opening a terminal by default when USB is inserted

Tags: command-line, usb, media

By default, when removable media is inserted Ubuntu will open Nautilus in the mount directory. I disabled this feature, but was wondering if I could configure Gnome to open a terminal in the mount directory instead.

EDIT: I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Have you checked out [this link](http://superuser.com/questions/556674/how-can-i-change-the-default-action-taken-on-removable-media-in-ubuntu/556735#556735) from what appears to be our user @Seth perhaps?

Comment: @Seth None of the options seem applicable, ie I don't see an option for USB or external hard drive.

Comment: You don't have a "removable media" option? (USB drive is removable media.)

Comment: @KGIII Under the removable media tab, there are options for CD Audio, DVD video, etc., but no USB.

Comment: Wow... I'm gonna need a minute. I think I have it. I'll type out an answer and give you a screenshot in a few - it will be a minute.

Comment: I could write you an udev-rule, are you interested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An edited version of [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/554413/72216) does the job.
When a (any) usb device is being connected, a `gnome-terminal` is opened in its (root) directory.

In the example, when a 14.04 `usb` startup flash drive is connected:

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import time

def get_mountedlist():
    return [(item.split()[0].replace("├─", "").replace("└─", ""),
             item[item.find("/"):]) for item in subprocess.check_output(
            ["lsblk"]).decode("utf-8").split("\n") if "/" in item]

def identify(disk):
    command = "find /dev/disk -ls | grep /"+disk
    output = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8")
    if "usb" in output:
        return True
    else:
        return False

done = []
while True:
    mounted = get_mountedlist()
    new_paths = [dev for dev in mounted if not dev in done and not dev[1] == "/"]
    valid = [dev for dev in new_paths if identify(dev[0]) == True]
    for item in valid:
        os.chdir(item[1])
        subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal"])
    done = mounted
    time.sleep(4)
```

#### How to use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `open_usb.py`
- Test- run the script. with the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/open_usb.py
  ```
- If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/open_usb.py
  ```

#### Notes

- I tested it on Unity (14.04), but it is unlikely it would break on *any* Ubuntu version, as long as it has the default configuration (including `python3`)
- The script only runs a very simple and lightweight check, every four seconds. In my tests, I could not determine *any* additional processor load.

---

### EDIT

As mentioned in a comment, although the script works as it should, one issue occurs when you *safely* remove the `usb` device: a warning is given that the volume is "occupied" by the script.

The cause is that the script `cd` -s into the directory of the volume, before opening the terminal in the root directory of the volume.

#### The solution

The solution is quite simple; make the script leave the directory again after having opened the terminal in the `usb` device's root directory. In the version below, the issue is fixed:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import time
home = os.environ["HOME"]

def get_mountedlist():
    return [(item.split()[0].replace("├─", "").replace("└─", ""),
             item[item.find("/"):]) for item in subprocess.check_output(
            ["lsblk"]).decode("utf-8").split("\n") if "/" in item]

def identify(disk):
    command = "find /dev/disk -ls | grep /"+disk
    output = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8")
    if "usb" in output:
        return True
    else:
        return False

done = []
while True:
    mounted = get_mountedlist()
    new_paths = [dev for dev in mounted if not dev in done and not dev[1] == "/"]
    valid = [dev for dev in new_paths if identify(dev[0]) == True]
    for item in valid:
        os.chdir(item[1])
        subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal"])
        os.chdir(home)
    done = mounted
    time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: @AlessandroPower Glad it works :)

Comment: Actually I have one last issue. When I try to safely remove a USB I am warned that open_usb.py is keeping the device busy. Do you know how this can be prevented?

Comment: @AlessandroPower I assume the terminal is still open then? (Since that is the only connection after the command has run)

Comment: No, I closed the terminal.

Comment: @AlessandroPower I'll look at it tonight (have some visitors :) )

Comment: Hi @AlessandroPower should be fixed now :)