# How can I automatically create a link on the desktop or in $HOME when USB Stick is mounted?

Tags: usb, mount, udev, symbolic-link, guest-session

How can I create(and remove if unplugged) a symlink to the mount-point of a newly plugged-in USB-device on the desktop or in the $HOME of the systems guest-account?

Comment: Is that USB-device always the **same** one ? Is it a usb memory stick or a HDD/SDD ?  Assuming you use `Unity`, would a relevant icon with mounted volume name appearing in the launch bar serve yr purpose, instead of having an (s-link) icon pop-up on the desktop ?

Comment: Cbhihe - the usb device is always some kind of storage device(mostly usb-memory stick), but not always the same and a launcher icon doesn't help it needs to be a symlink in the homedirectory of the currently logged in user(guest-account most of the time)

Comment: An USB device, inserted when in a guest session, will normally be mounted in `/media/guest-XXXXXX`. Since the username is unique for each session, creating a symlink would be a little tricky. Can you elaborate on why you would need such a symlink?

Comment: To answer Jacobs question, it's wouldn't be a problem if it would also run for other accounts. 
The problem that our users have, is that we use some java-tools that do not use the gnome-file-dialog but instead use the rather minimal jfiledialog. That does not have a devices list on the left hand side, and only presents the users with a list of "/", /home"  etc. 
Since our users can be pretty linux iliterate they are dependend on the gui to provide them a visible link to their usb-drives, so the workaround-idea is to create a link to the usb-drives there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question turns out to exist of two separate questions:

1. How to automatically create (and remove) a link on the desktop to mounted usb drives
2. How to run it on guest account

These questions are answered in `[1.]` and `[2.]` below.

### 1. Automatically create a desktop link to mounted usb drives (in general)

With a small background script, you can automatically have a link created on your desktop to the mounted usb drive(s), *and* automatically have it removed if the drive is removed.

[image][image]

#### The procedure; how it works

The script below is an edited version of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/694199/72216). This version:

- keeps an eye on newly mounted devices (using the command `lsblk`)
- if a new item shows up, it checks if the newly mounted device is a `usb` device by the command: `find /dev/disk -ls | grep <disk>`. If `usb` in the output, the new mount is valid.
- if the mount is valid, a link is created on the user's desktop, with the command: `ln -s <new_mount> <target>`.
  The targeted link is named: `[USB] <devicename>`.

*At the same time*

- The new mount is added to a list. periodically (once per four seconds), the list is checked. If the mount no longer exists, its corresponding link is removed from your desktop.

#### How to set up

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `show_usb.py`
2. create the directory `/opt/show_usb` (since we want to run it for a guest account):

   ```
   sudo mkdir /opt/show_usb
   ```
3. Copy the script into `/opt/show_usb`:

   ```
   sudo cp /path/to/show_usb.py /opt/show_usb
   ```
4. Test-run the script from a terminal by the command:

   ```
   python3 /opt/show_usb/show_usb.py
   ```
5. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   python3 /opt/show_usb/show_usb.py
   ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import time

def find_dtop():
    # get the localized path to the Desktop folder
    home = os.environ["HOME"]; dr_file = home+"/.config/user-dirs.dirs"
    return [home+"/"+ l.split("/")[-1].strip() \
            for l in open(dr_file).readlines() \
            if l.startswith("XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=")][0].replace('"', "")

def get_mountedlist():
    return [(item.split()[0].replace("├─", "").replace("└─", ""),
             item[item.find("/"):]) for item in subprocess.check_output(
            ["lsblk"]).decode("utf-8").split("\n") if "/" in item]

def identify(disk):
    cmd = "find /dev/disk -ls | grep /"+disk
    output = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8")
    return True if "usb" in output else False

done = []; check = []
dt = find_dtop()
while True:
    mnt = get_mountedlist(); mount_check = [item[1] for item in mnt]
    for item in check:
        if not item in mount_check:
            try:
                os.remove(dt+"/[USB] "+item.split("/")[-1]); check.remove(item)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass
    new_paths = [dev for dev in mnt if not dev in done and not dev[1] == "/"]
    valid = [dev for dev in new_paths if identify(dev[0]) == True]
    for item in valid:
        new = item[1]
        subprocess.Popen(["ln", "-s", new, dt+"/[USB] "+new.split("/")[-1] ])
        check.append(new)
    time.sleep(4)
    done = mnt
```

---

### 2. How to automatically run the script, specifically in guest account

To make the script autostart in a guest session:

1. Look if the directory `/etc/guest-session/skel/.config/autostart` exists. If not, create it:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /etc/guest-session/skel/.config/autostart
   ```
2. Now create a startup launcher for the guest account:

   ```
   sudo -i gedit /etc/guest-session/skel/.config/autostart/desktop_usb.desktop
   ```

   In the file that opens, paste the code below:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=USB_desktop
   Exec=python3 /opt/show_usb/show_usb.py
   Type=Application
   ```

   Save and close the file. Now when you log in on guest account, the script will run.

***That's it***

#### Notes

- More on how to edit the guest account [to be found here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession).
- The script only acts if a new drive is mounted and adds no noticeable load to the processor whatsoever.

Comment: `/etc/skel` is used for new **regular** accounts, so you should not mess with it only to affect guest sessions. If `/etc/guest-session/skel` does not exist, just create it!

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks for the hint! That will simplify the last section. Will edit...

Comment: thanks for the answer and sorry for the late response, work had me pretty occupied the last week, I'll try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Hey Jacob, sorry it tried the answer a few weeks ago but forgot to check it here, it works perfectly for what were trying to do.. Thank you very much.

Comment: @FlorianL. you're welcome :)